# After changing EF database connection, can't access all tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC4 mobile web site using Entity Framework 5 for my internship.

I started from a prototype done by my coworkers.

There are 2 projects: one for entities and another for mvc.

When doing the dev I was using a dev database but now that my work must be tested it must be connected to a another database.

So I change the connection string in `app.config` in the entity project and I have done the same for `web.config` on my mvc project.

But when I run my program, I can only access the table that my coworkers added to project not the one that I added.

I don't understand why i can access the data in some tables but not all.

Have someone already seen that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Update the model from data base. Open the yourModel.edmx file right click any where on the diagram and select update model from data base.

Comment: I just did that and now i have a bunch of errors. I get an error for all my entities  : 
Error 11007 : The type of entity 'Something' isn't map

Comment: you might get help from here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738478(v=vs.103).aspx) in resolving 11077